# Ubuntu doesn't recognise my wireless adapter

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu on my Acer laptop, but I can''t access the internet. As far as I can tell it is because my wireless adapter (built-in Broadcom 802.11g) is not recognised. I have windows 7 also on the laptop and it does recognise the wireless, so I can only assume it is something o do with Ubuntu. I suppose it might need a driver. I have read that I could try to connect my laptop via a cable to the router, but sadly I do not have a cable, nor do I have any access to one or to any shop that might sell it, so I hope there is some other solution, maybe by downloading via the windows setup. If anyone can provide any guidance or advice I would appreciate it. I am completely new to Ubuntu, so please bear this in mind.

Comment: did you try the "additional drivers" "program"?!

Comment: Check out the howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx It has both online and offline sections.

Comment: Thank you, though I wasn't able to find a solution there.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Thank you, yes I tried that, and it seemed to want to download a driver, but with there being no internet connection, it was not able to do it.

Comment: @PSellaz you can plug in a wired cable for 2 minutes?!

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Thanks again, but as noted in my OP I don't have a cable, nor access to one.

Comment: ahh, than you should download it somehow, put it on usb and install it

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen Thanks again. As per my comment to the answer by user68169 I have downloaded the drivers to the laptop using the windows 7 dualboot. So they are on the machine already - I just need to install them in Ubuntu. I don't have a USB or any other kind of removable storage.

Comment: ahh, just leave them in windows partition and copy them, easypeasy

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen - thanks, but *how* do I copy them from the windows partition ?

Comment: you can navigate to that disk by the file explorer?!

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen thanks again but where do I find "file explorer" ? I am using Ubuntu 11.10. From the Home folder I can see "File System" but in there I don't see anything that appears to be the windows partition....as I said in my OP I am completely new to Ubuntu so I may be looking in the wrong place ?

Comment: open an folder, and it should stay somehwere between
http://gyazo.com/ebb4c9bbf19a92d79c0feb85a22e5fc1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3662/discussion-between-p-sellaz-and-dr-bunsen)

Comment: seems I cant login to the chat, but is the file(s) you got .DEB?! then just use dpkg -i <name>.DEB

Comment: Hi @Dr_Bunsen, thanks again. The file I downloaded is hybrid-portsrc_x86_64-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz and extracting it produces a Makefile and a src folder and a lib folder

Answer (score 1):

If this is driver problem you could try to install Broadcom 802.11g drivers by downloading them from [Broadcom web site](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)
in your windows OS and then copy them to Ubuntu and try to install them there.

See if that will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. I have downloaded the drivers but how do I "copy them to Ubuntu and try to install them there" ?

Comment: I am not shore how WUBI installer works, but I guess you can access   
Windows partition anyway. So lets start.

Comment: First copy drivers to root of C:/ drive in Windows
Then boot up Ubuntu, mount Windows partition (C:/ drive)
Copy drivers from C: drive to Desktop in Ubuntu
To make things easier rename downloaded driver archive to _drivers_ (leave .tar.gz like _drivers.tar.gz_)
Now fire up terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T and type `cd Desktop`
Now we need to extract drivers from archive so type tar `-zxvf drivers.tar.gz`
Then type `cd drivers` next `./configure` next `make` next `make install` 
And now drivers should be installed. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I have got as far as extracting the drivers (there is a Makefile, and src folder and a lib folder) but ./configure gives "bash: ./configure: no such file or directory"

Comment: Can you please tell which version of ubuntu you have? Is it 12.04 32 Bit?

Comment: It is version 11.10 - 64 bit

Comment: It seems that you wont be able to compile this driver cause in broadcom website in readme file it says
That on Ubuntu, you will need headers and tools to compile driver.   `build-essential linux-headers-generic build-dep linux` but even after installing them I could not compile drivers..
So can you type this in terminal lspci `-vvnn | grep 14e4` so we can identify your wireless card. Post output here please. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. IT says:
Broadcom 4318 [Airforce One 54g] Wireless Lan Controller [14e4:4318]

Comment: Do you have your Ubuntu install disk or usb drive?
If yes then follow this page step by step [1.link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access)
All you really need to do is install b43-fwcutter from your install media CD-ROM or usb /pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/ and /pool/main/p/patch/
Just double click to install 'em.
Download these files 
[2.link](http://downloads.openwrt.org/sources/wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o)
[3.link](http://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2)
 And now do Step 3 and Step 4 from 1.link in this comment 
Done :)

Comment: Thanks again. No, I don't have an install CD. I installed it from within windows.

Comment: Ok in this case here is links to [b43-fwcutter](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/b43-fwcutter/b43-fwcutter_014-9_amd64.deb)
and to [patch](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/patch/patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) And don't forget to download files from 1.link (in previous comment)  step 2 in windows before booting up Ubuntu.
After downloading all files follow guide in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access) page starting from Step 3

Comment: OK I downloaded the 4 files in windows and rebooted back to ubuntu. Nothing happens when I double click them in ubuntu, but when I try this from the link you gave "sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter" it seems to try to install something then gives errors saying it can't resolve "archive.ubuntu.com" - so I've rebooted back into windows to make this comment. This is really getting me down now. Every time I comment I have to reboot :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is ultimate guide for this issue.

**First Step**

Install Downloaded files ( b43-fwcutter and patch)
Right Click on file Or Double Click
[image: Right Click on file Or Double Click]

Click Install
[image: Click Install]

**Second Step**
Copy the downloaded files (wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o *and* broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2) to your *home* folder and execute the following commands consecutively in a terminal to extract and install the firmware:

```
tar xfvj broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2
```

[image]
After hitting enter you should see something like this

Now enter

```
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware wl_apsta-3.130.20.0.o
```

and hit eneter

[image]

And something like this should come out..

[image]

Now enter

```
sudo b43-fwcutter --unsupported -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5/driver/wl_apsta_mimo.o
```

After terminal have done it's job exit terminal.

And you should be able to activate drivers In Additional Drivers
[image]

Select Drivers and click Activate

[image]

**Note:** A computer restart may be required before using the wifi card.

Comment: Thanks, but the "install" button on the "utility for extracing Broadcomm ...." screen is greyed out.....

Comment: WOW never had that before :D I recommend you to reinstall Ubuntu to 12.04. You installed Ubuntu from Windows with WUBI right? So that should not be a problem to uninstall 11.10 and instal 12.04... On 12.04 should not be this issue any more. Sorry that I could not help you with this..

**before this try " `gksudo software-center & exit` " in terminal** See if that helps with install button